# How to specify which class loader should class.getClassLoader() return?

Tags: java, annotations, classloader, urlclassloader

I have a project with one general part and several "implementation-specific", used through wrappers where the implementation is loaded using URLClassLoader (which has common class loader as parent). Now, there is a generic class A annotated by @Foo, which is rather implementation-specific.

```
@Foo
public class A { ... }
```

A is first loaded via implementation-specific code, therefore it starts with URLClassLoader, but it tries the loading in parent - which can load the class as it is generic one (and I need to be able to instantiate the class in generic code, although I don't need to access the annotation).

Then, the implementation checks for the annotation @Foo but it is not found, as Java runtime tries to load the annotation via A.class.getClassLoader() which is not the generic one.

Obviously, I can't change Java Runtime, but is there a way how I could let URLClassLoader declare the class to be loaded by it (but keep the dirty work on parent - and also let him register the class so that I can instantiate it by the generic parent)?

Comment: I'm not totally sure of what you are really trying to achieve - load the class by the parent ("generic one") ClassLoader but let `getClass()` return the child-URLClassLoader instead? This is not possible as the returned class will always return the class-loader which defined its bytes. For the loading of `@Foo`, as `A.class.getClassLoader()` returns a reference to URLClassLoader, on trying to load `Foo` it looksup its local cache, then asks his ancestors if they know the class-definition for it and only if non knew it it tries to define it itself.

Comment: As you set the parent (did you?) of URLClassLoader to be your "generic one" and this "generic one" should know how `Foo` needs to be defined, URLClassLoader should be able to return a class object for that Foo too - else you have troubles within your setup. And as always - a little bit of code is way more descriptive than your textual description - at least I have troubles understanding your demands

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's really not possible (probably for good reasons). The class.getClassLoader() returns the loader which actually called defineClass(), and findLoadedClass() returns the class which it has defined. Therefore, I can't let the class be defined in child loader and still return the loaded class in parent.

I have resolved the situation by loading class A in the child loader (not giving that accessible from parent loader), and passing this child loader to any place where I need to load the class, although it's rather generic - as I load it by reflection anyway, it works.